# Fetch row from table having two specified for another column

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
movie_id genre_id
6           2
6           7
3           2
```

I need to fetch movie_id having genre_id as both 2 and 7 using subquery and not join.

Comment: Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd query movies with genres 2 and 7, and count the number of distinct genres:

```
SELECT   movie_id
FROM     mytable
WHERE    genre_id IN (2, 7)
GROUP BY movie_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT genere_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group By` with `Having` to filter:

```
SELECT 
  movie_id 
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY movie_id 
HAVING SUM(genre_id = 2) AND 
       SUM(genre_id = 7)
```